# UndefinedFunctionException Attempted to call function xxx from namespace xxx

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have this error (under silex 2.0):

> UndefinedFunctionException in app.php line 88: Attempted to call function "postIndexArticle" from namespace "SocialWall\Controller".

```
in app.php line 88
at {closure}(object(Application)) in Container.php line 113
at Container->offsetGet('home.controller') in CallbackResolver.php line 55
at CallbackResolver->convertCallback('home.controller') in ServiceControllerResolver.php line 50
at ServiceControllerResolver->getController(object(Request)) in HttpKernel.php line 136
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 68
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in Application.php line 496
at Application->handle(object(Request)) in Application.php line 477
at Application->run() in index.php line 17
```

my app.php

```
<?php

use SocialWall\Controller;

$app['home.controller'] = function($app) {
    return SocialWall\Controller\postIndexArticle($app);
};
```

my route.php

```
<?php

// Home page
$app->get('/', 'home.controller')->bind('home');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace SocialWall\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use SocialWall\DAO\ArticleDAO;

function postIndexArticle(Application $app) {
    return function() use ($app) {
        return new $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array('articles' => $app['dao.article']->findAll()));
    };
}
```

I need help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate your demo and it works for me. I see you're following the last example shown here http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/service_controller.html that mentions using callables as controllers:

```
// app.php
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'HomeController.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider());

$app['home.controller'] = function($app) {
    return \SocialWall\Controller\postIndexArticle($app);
};

// Home page
$app->get('/', 'home.controller')->bind('home');

$app->run();
```

And then the controller is in a separate file:

```
// HomeController.php
namespace SocialWall\Controller;

use Silex\Application;

function postIndexArticle(Application $app) {
    return function() use ($app) {
        return $app['twig']->createTemplate('test template')->render([]);
    };
}
```

This prints just `test template`.

So I think the problem is in one of these things (or maybe both):

1. Your `postIndexArticle`'s inner callable returns `return new $app['twig']->render(...` which is incorrect. You don't want to use the keyword `new` here because `render()` method returns just string template.
2. I think there's something wrong with your namespaces in your `app.php` or `HomeController.php` where you want to call

   ```
   $app['home.controller'] = function($app) {
       return SocialWall\Controller\postIndexArticle($app);
   };
   ```

   So try using absolute namespace path as I did with `\SocialWall\Controller\postInd...`

Comment: Ok it's work now : I have just add "require_once __DIR__.'/../src/Controller/HomeController.php';" in my index.php ! And remove "new" in return of controller as you wrote.

Comment: That's why using this method feels fishy to me :(. Needing require_once means returning back to the past. Autoload is great please use it.

Comment: You say the callable as controller is a great method if using whit Autoload ?

Comment: I'm using `require_once 'HomeController.php';` just because I don't want to spend too much time with the demo. You should configure composer to autoload your classes as well see: https://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer

Answer (score 0):

You should use classes not functions, I would use

my app.php

```
<?php

use SocialWall\Controller;

$app['home.controller'] = function($app) {
    return SocialWall\Controller\HomeController($app);
};
```

my route.php

```
<?php

// Home page
$app->get('/', 'home.controller:postIndexArticle')->bind('home');
```

Homecontroller.php

```
<?php

namespace SocialWall\Controller;

use Silex\Application;
use SocialWall\DAO\ArticleDAO;

class HomeController
{
  protected $app;

  public function __construct(Application $app)
  {
    $this->app= $app;
  }

  function postIndexArticle() {
        return $this->app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array('articles' => $this->app['dao.article']->findAll()));
  }
}
```

As a side note using $app directly everywhere is not recommended. You should read about DI.

Comment: Ok but If you look at the end of documentation page (http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/service_controller.html) you will see "In addition to using classes for service controllers..." and just below, their controller is a simple function. Why ? I think I don't understand this part of documentation, can you explain me ?

Comment: I just read it but I never even thought of using a simple function, for me a service is a class and that's it. I don't even want to know how you get your request or route parameters with a simple function. Too complicated for me.